# How to read data from config.properties file line by line in JAVA on the server side not on the client side

Tags: javascript, java

i have a config.prop file where i have set key value pairs(key=name,value=url's)

this is a sample value. I have 20-30 key-value pair like this dividing into 4 different sets. Like user 1 can see first 5 URL's which are coming in the config. prop file and goes on for user-2, user-3, user-4 which see's the next 5 URL's

```
FILE_TT="";
```

My application is running dynamic and wants to read the urls line by line from the config.properties file so that when the next user comes it shows only that url's which are specified for that user. any idea? or another suggestion where I can read the key-value pair. I don't want any hardcoded method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Properties which is a hashtable implementation

```
File f=new File("Complete path of your config file");
            InputStream i=new FileInputStream(f);
            Properties p =new Properties();
            p.load(i);
         String value= p.getProperty("key"); //you can search for a property
```

Comment: This is for reading the line..Now i want to set some statement where i can compare in the file if ( this=='')  then shows this urls and same goes for other statements.How can i do this ?? basically in the config.prop file there are a set of 4  different groups and they contains 10 key value pair (urls) each means (40 total) .How can i show each set .and these 4 sets are different mean one user has to see 10 urls only and next will see the other 10 not the previous 10 urls